# intelliJ lombok annotation aren't refreshing

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

I'm using maven + lombok 1.18.12 + intelliJ 2020.2 with lombok plugin (0.30-EAP) and Enable annotation processing is checked (Annotation Processors menu).

When I'm updating class (add field or lombok annotation), annotation aren't processed and autocomplete not working. However, they are processed and autocomplete worked correctly when I close + restart intelliJ.

Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the rootcause:

https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/649#issuecomment-665861668